# Homepage animation intro ala apple.com

Tags: javascript

How can I mimic Apple.com's intro animation first used with the updated MacBook Air & Currently with the iPad 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. Create the website with everything shown as normal
2. Add `display: hidden;` (CSS) to every visible element on the page
3. Use jQuerys' `fadeIn()` to fade in the elements
4. Use `setTimeout()` to time these `fadeIn()`'s to get the desired effect

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wcqzd/ - it needs some work but it should give you a good base.